# Prevent Emacs from reading the OS X clipboard?

Tags: macos, emacs

How can I prevent GNU Emacs.app on OS X from reading from reading from the OS X keyboard unless explicitly asked to?

For example, if I yank something from emacs, then copy something to the OS X clipboard, I don't want a subsequent put to paste from the clipboard — I'd like it to be whatever was last yank'd.

Comment: btw OS X itself also has 2 clipboards: one for Cmd-C/X/V and one for Emacs style Ctrl-K/Y, which are available almost globally.

Comment: It does! But the Emacs-style kill buffer is bound to individual text inputs. And I would really prefer it if Emacs would leave the main clipboard alone :(

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled by the variables `interprogram-paste-function` and `interprogram-cut-function`, if they are bound to a function, the function is called to retrieve whatever is in the system clipboard or setting the clipboard. You can disable this by setting them to `nil`:

```
(setq interprogram-paste-function nil)
(setq interprogram-cut-function nil)
```

Comment: This also breaks explicit copy+paste :(

Comment: So you have to make new commands and bindings that bind those variables to default values when you want to explicitly "copy+paste".